# Show link to open overflowed div

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` with `ul` inside it. `ul` can contain an unknown number of elements. Each element can contain different amounts of content. It can be long or short lines of text.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Augrd

This `DIV` when the page is loaded should not be more than 100px in height.

What I want to achieve: if inside this DIV is too much content and it is overflowed, then I want to display the link on which the user can click and "open" this DIV making it more in height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This detects the natural height of your `<div>` and automatically generates a "More..." link when the natural height of the `<div>` is greater than its current height (it does not show one if 100px is enough to show all the contents). You do not have to adjust the javascript for different heights of the `<div>`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thUFP/3/)

Javascript

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var original_height = main.offsetHeight;
main.style.height = 'auto';
var natrual_height = main.offsetHeight;
main.style.height = original_height+"px";;
var more = document.getElementById("more");
if (natrual_height > original_height) {
  more.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="show_more()">More...</a>';
}
function show_more() {
  if (main.offsetHeight < natrual_height) {
      main.style.height = 'auto';
      more.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="show_more()">Less...</a>';
  } else {
      main.style.height = original_height+"px";;
      more.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="show_more()">More...</a>';
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main" class="main">
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>1234</li>
 <li>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</li>
  <li>5678</li>
  <li>111111</li>
  <li>abc</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="more">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Antony your code works great. But I have one more simple question. Is it possible to hide piece of text which is not fully placed in a DIV? Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/0w0n1Q0k1T2Q

Comment: @Derp You may need to set fixed `font-size` and `line-height` in CSS and use multiples of `line-height` as the height of the `<div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/thUFP/5/

Answer (score 0):

I have done updated your html and put some javascript. I hope it works for you.

html :

```
<div class="main">
<div id="ulist">

  <ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>1234</li>
 <li>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</li>
  <li>5678</li>
  <li>111111</li>
  <li>abc</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <div id='more' onclick="opendiv()">
    open
  </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#ulist {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

javscript :

```
  function opendiv()
{
  if(document.getElementById('more').innerHTML == 'open')
  {
  document.getElementById('ulist').style.height = '100%';
  document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = 'close';
  }
  else
  {
  document.getElementById('ulist').style.height = '100px';
  document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = 'open';
  }
}
```